# Get UserName based upon emai id log in from Database into asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, wcf

I am using WCF Library(which contains Buisness logic), Asp.Net C# Web pages(Home page, Welcome Page), SqlServer,
how to get username when user logged in with email id and password and that username can be Display in all web pages in asp.net website. How it possible? pls help me..

Comment: Use [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

Write a stored procedure to retrieve all the user related data that needs to be used frequently used in the application and store it in a session. Manipulated session according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Create list of the things you want across all the web pages & keep it in session.